# Combine two commands into one command

Tags: command-line, ps

How can i combine these two commands **`ps aux | head -n1 ; ps aux | grep vlc`** into one command? I tried to use `tee` command (`ps aux | tee >(head -n1) >(grep vlc)`) but it didn't work!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @CarlH : Exactly what Oil just posted!

Comment: @HBS -1: So we have to read the answer to figure the question?

Comment: @muru: Oftentimes, beginners at new fields do not know how to ask questions as clearly or concisely as experts. Some might say this defines a beginner, since even experts are always asking questions.  On Stack Exchange, it seems commonplace for an expert, upon seeing a confusingly worded question, to ask *What are you trying to do?* to prompt the asker to reword their question. In this case, Oli was able to interpret HBS's question when Carl H wasn't. Instead of clarifying his question, as HBS was prompted to do, he instead pointed to the answer, which should resolve Carl H's uncertainty.

Comment: @user1717828 so? Hbs won't even try to improve his question, and your justifying that?

Comment: @user1717828 Thanks for implying that I'm an expert (I'm honestly not!), but the reason I asked what he was trying to do was because I suspected there may be a better way to do it. And there was - the accepted answer does not actually combine the two commands into one, which is what the question asked, but it does solve the OP's problem. The question was not really about combining commands, but about controlling the output of ps.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So you're trying to preserve the head of the PS command (so you can see the headers) but only show `vlc` commands.

I'd personally just use `awk` and filter based on two conditions, the line number and the VLC. If either are true, we output the line:

```
$ ps aux | awk 'NR==1 || $11~/vlc/'
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
oli       4833  0.6  0.2 795220 62952 ?        Sl   15:37   0:00 /usr/bin/vlc
```

It has the added advantage that you're only running `ps` once. And because field 11 is the main command (not any of its arguments), we won't capture the `awk` command being run either. We just get VLC and the column headers.

---

On a sidebar, **something like this *should* work... but doesn't...**

```
ps aux | tee >(head -1 >&2) | grep vlc
```

You were close, you needed to pipe into the last command or `tee` will sploodge over STDOUT, and if you output to STDOUT and then pipe, chances are it'll be caught up in the latter `grep`. In the above I output the headers into STDERR (2) to stop `grep` interfering with it. Bit hacky but hey-ho.

But yes, **this still doesn't work**. The reason is that [`head` closes STDOUT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47936/880), which filters back to `tee` and arrests the `grep`. This is by design so `head` doesn't process more input than it needs to. You can simulate what it's doing with `awk`:

```
$ ps aux | tee >(awk 'NR==1 {print;exit}' >&2) | grep "grep"
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

This is equivalent to `head -1`. It finds the first line and then exits. This kills off the input buffer, and `tee` flips out.

Here's a version where `awk` doesn't quit after it finds the first line. It'll keep running (good thing or not) over every line:

```
$ ps aux | tee >(awk 'NR==1' >&2) | grep "grep"
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
oli      15103  0.0  0.0  11752  2236 pts/18   S+   11:32   0:00 grep --color=auto grep
```

Another alternative is sending the input into `sponge`. Sponge soaks up the whole input stream before writing it to a file (or being redirected). This stops head killing off the parent stream but it does mean the input will be reversed (the `grep` will output first) so we'll push that through a `sponge` instance too:

```
$ ps aux | tee >(sponge >(head -1 >&2)) | sponge >(grep "grep")
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
oli      14875  0.0  0.0  11752  2192 pts/18   S    11:19   0:00 grep --color=auto grep
```

But while these second two both work, and you're only generating `ps aux` output once, **they still both have serious issues**. The `awk|grep` is processing everything twice and the `sponge` orgy is buffering everything twice.

**tl;dr**: If you can process it all in one command like you can with `awk`, why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 8):

You can tell `ps` to print only the process IDs of `vlc` with `-C`.

From `man ps`:

```
   -C cmdlist
          Select by command name.  This selects the processes whose
          executable name is given in cmdlist.
```

Example:

```
$ ps u -C vlc
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
sylvain  12586  0.1  0.3 1076848 60908 ?       Sl   20:10   0:00 /usr/bin/vlc
```

Answer (score 7):

Use `bash` process substitution and `cat` :

```
cat <(ps aux | head -1) <(ps aux | grep '[v]lc')
```

The process substitution pattern `<()` replaces the output of the command inside it as a file. `cat` will simple concatenate the files as usual.

Example :

```
$ cat <(ps aux | head -1) <(ps aux | grep '[v]lc')
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
chayan   26031  2.3  0.4 1098532 38556 pts/31  Sl   20:45   0:00 vlc
```

Comment: That's doing essentially the same thing as in the OP's question, but adds an useless `cat`.

Comment: You are doing it the other way round than the OP. I think that it is apparent that the OP wanted to run just a single instance of the source of the data - `ps aux`.

Answer (score 6):

I would use

```
ps aux | grep -E '^USER|vlc'
```

you can add `| grep -v grep` to exclude the grep line

Comment: i would suggest to search for something unique like `%MEM`, `%CPU` rather than `USER` as `USER` itself is a valid username..

Answer (score 6):

Just tell `ps` to only show the output for `vlc`:

```
$ ps -P $(pgrep vlc)
PID PSR TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
6728   2 pts/0    Sl     0:00 vlc
```

`pgrep` lists the PIDs of any processes whose name matches the pattern given. ps's `-P` switch lets you list info only for specific PIDs. Combining the two gives you the `ps` header and only the lines you care about.